# Proper IF Statement python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

Hi I wanted to select certain data from my dataframe as shown below. Somehow my If statement does not work properly and selects, e.g. instead of 6M and 6M3M all of the possibilities which means 6M, 3M and 6M3M. I would like to play with the if statement. The code looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['Alex', 'Germany', '6M', 28, 'Surfer'],        
        ['Paul', 'Germany', '6M', 25,  'Surfer'],        
        ['Carly', 'Germany', '6M', 22,  'Surfer'],          
        ['Richard', 'Germany', '6M', 20,  'Surfer'],          
        ['Lee', 'UK', '6M3M', 22,  'Kite'],       
        ['Bob', 'UK', '6M3M', 23,  'Kite'],       
        ['Judith', 'UK', '6M3M', 29,  'Kite'],       
        ['Stephan', 'Spain', '3M', 29,  'Basketball'],       
        ['Wendy', 'Spain', '3M', 23,  'Basketball'],       
        ['Dennis', 'Spain', '3M', 25,  'Basketball'],
        ['Tucker', 'Germany', '3M', 22,  'Basketball'],        
        ['Paula', 'Germany', '3M', 21,  'Basketball'],          

        ], columns=['Name', 'Country', 'Course', 'Age', 'Sport'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if (row['Country'] == 'Germany') or (row['Country'] == 'UK') or (row['Course'] == '6M') or (row['Course'] == '6M3M'):
        print(row['Name'], row['Country'], row['Age'], row['Sport'], row['Course'])
```

My Output looks like:

```
Alex Germany 28 Surfer 6M
Paul Germany 25 Surfer 6M
Carly Germany 22 Surfer 6M
Richard Germany 20 Surfer 6M
Lee UK 22 Kite 6M3M
Bob UK 23 Kite 6M3M
Judith UK 29 Kite 6M3M
Tucker Germany 22 Basketball 3M
Paula Germany 21 Basketball 3M
```

But I wanted to have only:

```
Alex Germany 28 Surfer 6M
Paul Germany 25 Surfer 6M
Carly Germany 22 Surfer 6M
Richard Germany 20 Surfer 6M
Lee UK 22 Kite 6M3M
Bob UK 23 Kite 6M3M
Judith UK 29 Kite 6M3M
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Using `or` instead of `|` solves half the problem. The rest is using the wrong operators. It should be `if row['Country'] in ['Germany', 'UK'] and row['Course'] in ['6M', '6M3M']`

Comment: @Farhan.K, Thanksa  that is what I was looking for!  Could you please add it as answer.

Comment: @Farhan.K: go ahead, it's back open now that the pipes have been replaced with `or`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` logic is not correct. It should be:

```
if row['Country'] in {'Germany', 'UK'} and row['Course'] in {'6M', '6M3M'}:
        print(row['Name'], row['Country'], row['Age'], row['Sport'], row['Course'])
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112149/5270506) for an explanation on using `in` in an `if` statement.